# How to detect manufacturer from NFC tag using Android?

Tags: android, tags, nfc, fingerprinting

I am trying to detect the manufacturer name for an NFC tag. I found manufacturer codes [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1814558). But I can detect only Mifare Ultralight C tags using these IDs. The first byte of Ultralight C tag ID represents the manufacturer code. But other tags do not contain this property. [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite&hl=en) can detect the IC manufacturer. Is it possible to detect the manufacturer for other NFC tags?

Comment: You may check these two threads:  [How to detect the type of an NFC chip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083339/how-to-detect-the-type-of-an-nfc-chip)  and [NFC tag information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058009/nfc-tag-information/24058630#24058630)

Comment: I have already read those answers. But can only detect mifare tags. But can not detect manufacturer of other tags like Felica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is certainly no one-catches-all approach to this. Fingerprinting of NFC tags (to guess the manufacturer or even the exact tag type) is rather difficult and you will probably need to obtain the various datasheet/user manuals for the different tag types that you want to detect. Even then, most tags don't just tell you "I am XY developed by Z". In some application use-cases it is even considered undesirable (typically for security-by-obscurity reasons) to reveal the manufacturer or product code.

For certain tag types, however, there *are* well-established mechanisms to obtain a manufacturer identifier:

- `NfcA` tags that have a 7-byte UID (get it via `Tag.getId()`) encode the manufacturer's ISO 7816-6 registered chip manufacturer code (cf. the [list that you already found](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1814558), a [newer list](http://www.kartenbezogene-identifier.de/de/chiphersteller-kennungen.html), or the [JTC1/SC17 document library](http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=8915579&objAction=browse&viewType=1)) as the first byte of that UID. E.g. `0x02` for STMicroelectronics, `0x04` for NXP, `0x05` for Infineon, etc.
- `NfcV` tags have an 8-byte UID where the manufacturer's ISO 7816-6 registered chip manufacturer code (same as for 7-byte-UID `NfcA` tags) is encoded as the second byte of the UID (note the different byte order for `NfcV` which results in that byte being the second last byte obtained through `Tag.getId()`).
- `NfcF` tags typically have an RF front-end that comes from Sony (at least I'm not aware of any other manufacturers). That front-end may be integrated into products by other manufacturers though. Sony provides a [series of datasheet/user manuals](http://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/tech-support/index.html) that give you sufficient information to distinuguish between different FeliCa tags.
- Some `IsoDep` tags (specifically those that are smartcards following [GlobalPlatform](https://www.globalplatform.org/) specifications) may reveals manufacturer information through their card production life-cycle data (CPLC). See [Nikolay's blog post](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/08/android-secure-element-execution.html) and the GP specifications on how to get that from typical GP compliant cards. See [CPLC.java](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader/tree/master/src/main/java/sasc/smartcard/app/globalplatform/CPLC.java) on how to interpret that information.